# In Android Studio, I am attempting to create a home page resembling the layout of Instagram's feed, where posts are displayed

Tags: java, android, mobile, apk

In Android Studio, I am attempting to create a home page resembling the layout of Instagram's feed, where posts are displayed. However, I am encountering a null pointer exception.
""

```
main activity class 
package com.example.petapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Post> postList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
      postList.add(new Post("User1", "Description1", R.drawable.a, "Date1", "Location1", R.drawable.a));
        postList.add(new Post("User1", "Description1", R.drawable.a, "Date1", "Location1", R.drawable.a));

        // Assuming you have a List<Post> named postList containing your posts
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this::onNavigationItemSelected);
    }
    private void initializePostList() {
        // Initialize the postList with some dummy data (replace it with your actual data)

        // Add more dummy posts as needed
    }


    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        if (itemId == R.id.action_home) {
            // Handle Home button click
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.action_add) {
            // Handle Explore button click
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Explore Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.action_profile) {
            // Handle Profile button click
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

adapter class

```
package com.example.petapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> postList;

    public PostAdapter(List<Post> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post post = postList.get(position);
        holder.bind(post);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView usernameTextView;
        private TextView descriptionTextView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView dateTextView;
        private TextView locationTextView;
        private ImageView imgProfileImageView;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            usernameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameMain);
            descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            locationTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            imgProfileImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        }

        public void bind(Post post) {
            usernameTextView.setText(post.getUsername());
            descriptionTextView.setText(post.getDescription());
            imageView.setImageResource(post.getImageResource());
            dateTextView.setText(post.getDate());
            locationTextView.setText(post.getLocation());
            imgProfileImageView.setImageResource(post.getImgProfile());
        }
    }
}
```

post class

```
package com.example.petapp;

public class Post {
    private String username;
    private String description;
    private int imageResource;
    private String date;
    private String location;
    private int imgProfile;

    public Post(String username, String description, int imageResource, String date, String location, int imgProfile) {
        this.username = username;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.date = date;
        this.location = location;
        this.imgProfile = imgProfile;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public int getImgProfile() {
        return imgProfile;
    }
}
```

post_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:text="alain"
            android:textColor="#919191"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/usernameMain"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameMain" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameMain"
            android:layout_width="194dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="username"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1000dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="298dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/usernameMain"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="username"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:text="12/12/2024"
            android:textColor="#919191"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/usernameMain"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameMain" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/sum"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <!-- Centered Title -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/line1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/line2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.642" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#5A5A5A"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="593dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this the error that I'm facing:

```
2024-03-26 20:01:18.458  8348-8348  AndroidRuntime          com.example.petapp                   D  Shutting down VM
2024-03-26 20:01:18.458  8348-8348  AndroidRuntime          com.example.petapp                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.petapp, PID: 8348
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.petapp/com.example.petapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.petapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

I provided the code to the GPT, but it is simply producing nonsensical responses.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong and where it is wrong:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.petapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)` - the object at line 24 in MainActivity is null. Make it not null. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 1):

You do `postList.add` before you have actually initialised `postList`

You can do this like so

```
private List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>;
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but the error still there, just to make sure u mean like this right.
"public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();"
this is the error that i face "                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
"

Comment: It looks like you have a new error, that stack trace is different.